# JQuery works with id but not with class

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery for the search bar. To write "Search..." when not selected. the problem I encountered was that jQuery didn't work when I used "class" but it did work when I used "id". I wonder what the problem is.

Below are my codes:

Html

```
<form class="search-form" action="search.php" method="GET" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <label class="search-form_label">
    <input class="search-form_input" id="search" type="text" name="s" autocomplete="off" placeholder=""/>
    <span class="search-form_liveout"></span>
  </label>
  <button class="search-form_submit fa-search" type="submit">search</button>
</form>
```

Script code that did work:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

    // Add the value of "Search..." to the input field and a class of .empty
    $("#search").val("Search...").addClass("empty");

    // When you click on #search
    $("#search").focus(function(){

        // If the value is equal to "Search..."
        if($(this).val() == "Search...") {
            // remove all the text and the class of .empty
            $(this).val("").removeClass("empty");;
        }

    });

    // When the focus on #search is lost
    $("#search").blur(function(){

        // If the input field is empty
        if($(this).val() == "") {
            // Add the text "Search..." and a class of .empty
            $(this).val("Search...").addClass("empty"); 
        }

    });

});
    </script>
```

Script code that didn't work:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

    // Add the value of "Search..." to the input field and a class of .empty
    $(".search-form_input").val("Search...").addClass("empty");

    // When you click on #search
    $(".search-form_input").focus(function(){

        // If the value is equal to "Search..."
        if($(this).val() == "Search...") {
            // remove all the text and the class of .empty
            $(this).val("").removeClass("empty");;
        }

    });

    // When the focus on #search is lost
    $(".search-form_input").blur(function(){

        // If the input field is empty
        if($(this).val() == "") {
            // Add the text "Search..." and a class of .empty
            $(this).val("Search...").addClass("empty"); 
        }

    });

});
    </script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Add the value of "Search..." to the input field and a class of .empty
  $(".search-form_input").val("Search...").addClass("empty");

  // When you click on #search
  $(".search-form_input").focus(function() {

    // If the value is equal to "Search..."
    if ($(this).val() == "Search...") {
      // remove all the text and the class of .empty
      $(this).val("").removeClass("empty");;
    }

  });

  // When the focus on #search is lost
  $(".search-form_input").blur(function() {

    // If the input field is empty
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      // Add the text "Search..." and a class of .empty
      $(this).val("Search...").addClass("empty");
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="search-form" action="search.php" method="GET" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <label class="search-form_label">
            <input class="search-form_input" id="search" type="text" name="s" autocomplete="off" placeholder=""/>
            <span class="search-form_liveout"></span>
          </label>
  <button class="search-form_submit fa-search" type="submit">search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You code works, I have added the snippet, Can  you reproduce it?

Comment: $(".search-form_input") will most likely return an array, so Jquery might error because of that try $(".search-form_input")[0].val("Search...").addClass("empty")

Comment: Do you have multiple `.search-form_input` classes?

Comment: @Satpal where have you addded the snippet?

@ AvalothOath Will do. thank you.

@ ConorReidd No, that is the only one.

Comment: In the question, Can't you see "Show code snippet"?

Comment: ahh..now I see it. Thank you!